# VBA Error on Excel: Method or Data Member not found

Tags: vba, excel

My code:

```
Public Sub splitUpRegexPattern()
Dim regEx As New RegExp
Dim strPattern As String
Dim strInput As String
Dim strReplace As String
Dim Myrange As Range

Set Myrange = ActiveSheet.Range("B2:B4279")

For Each c In Myrange
    strPattern = "([A-Z]{2}\/[A-Z]{2}\/[A-Z][0-9]{2}\/[a-z]{3}[0-9]{9}\/)([0-9]{4})"

    If strPattern <> "" Then
        strInput = c.Value
        strReplace = "$1"

        With regEx
            .Global = True
            .MultiLine = True
            .IgnoreCase = False
            .Pattern = strPattern
        End With

        If regEx.test(strInput) Then
            c.Offset(0, 1) = regEx.Replace(strInput, "$2")
        Else
            c.Offset(0, 1) = ""
        End If
    End If
Next
```

End Sub

It was initially working well, it would give me an error, but still complete the task it was doing. But when I use this macro on a new spreadsheet, it gives me the error:

`Compile Error: Method or Data Member not found.`

All the solutions on this site are tailored to different situations, so I couldn't apply them to my circumstance unfortunately.

I have no idea why this is happening, as I haven't changed any of the code. I am sure if I had a greater understanding with VBA script that I would be able to understand this, but I do not, so I came to find out if someone here could help me!

Thanks!

Aydan

Comment: Could be the object that you are making an instance `RegExp`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a reference to a library called "**Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5**" to make it work.

If this code works in a workbook that simply means you have added that library reference and when you copy the code to a new workbook there you will need to add the same reference again.

In the existing code you are auto instantiating the variable called redEx which assumes that the library reference has been already added to make it work properly.

To avoid this, you may use the late binding technique which will not require you to add the reference and the code will work on any workbook.

To do so declare the regEx variable as an Object like below...

```
Dim regEx As Object
Set regEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
```

Answer (score 3):

My best guess is that you've lost a reference to a library. In VBE, select Tools - References. Find *Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5* and tick it.